# How To Animate Line Renderer Tiled Texture In Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, animation, graphics, mask

I would like to reproduce the draw line effect you see in hearthstone where a line is drawn and the tiled texture of the line animates along the path.

Here is a video reference:
https://youtu.be/68usg4ELkYI

I have the draw line from point to point working and I know how to set a tiled texture. My question is how do you animate the texture so it slides forward and fades.

For reference here is my code for my drawline:

```
[SerializeField]
LineRenderer _lineRenderer;
private void drawLineFromCardToCursor()
{
    var mousePos = Input.mousePosition;
    mousePos.z = 10.35f; // Distance from camera to world
    Vector3 worldPoint = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(mousePos);
    // Must move it forward by 1 so it appears in front of screens
    worldPoint.z = -0.001f;
    _lineRenderer.SetPosition(0, start);
    _lineRenderer.SetPosition(1, end);
}
```

And here is my tiling setup for my line renderer:

[image]

Please advise if you know how to make the tiling animate forward (and bonus if it includes fading in and out at the ends).

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set `Texture Mode` to `Tile`.

And then offset the texture:

```
lineRenderer.material.SetTextureOffset("_MainTex", Vector2.right * Time.time);
```

Comment: Ooops on the Tile mode yea it was set at that before but I was playing around. But your set texture offset is an interesting note, I will take a look at that. Thank you for the suggestions!

Comment: @Aggressor, Iggy could you please have a look into this? I followed the same but it doesn't work for me. https://stackoverflow.com/q/71347922/906414